# How to include packages that are downloaded and configured by NuGet in a WiX installer project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, installation, nuget

I know, if there are just DLLs downloaded via NuGet I can have WiX copy it during installation. But my question is, is there a way to include packages installed by NuGet into WiX MSI installer project ?

e.g. If there are setup/installer (EXE/MSI) packages downloaded and installed by NuGet, how best I can install them through a WiX installer? Do I need to find all such setup downloaded by NuGet and create a WiX bootstrap-chainer project ?

I have this question because I feel, developers use NuGet to get packages while development, but for users using the final product, they would probably install final product using a setup or installer, in my case created using WiX. So the WiX installer must also install/copy the packages (dlls, exes, etc.) downloaded using NuGet.

I am using VS 2012 Express update 4.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you a specific example of what you're trying to achieve? Do you mean you also want to include the DLL's which the NuGet package is dependent on?

Comment: To answer your question, please read my question thoroughly!